# Yii2 - GridView shows "(not set)" If a related Model's column is in list and getting filtered

Tags: activerecord, gridview, yii2

I have two tables/models Computer and Mainboard

`Computer` - with following columns/fields:

- id
- name
- mainboard_Id
- serial_number
- ...

`Mainboard` - with following columns/fields:

- id
- name
- type
- serial_number
- ...

Those models are in a one-to-one relationship.

In the `Computer` model I have the following method:

```
    public function getMainboard() {
        return $this->hasOne(Mainboard::className(), ['id' => 'mainboard_id']);
    }
```

The view contains following GridView:

```
    echo GridView::widget([
      'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
      'filterModel' => null,
      'columns' => [
        'id',
        'name',
        'mainboard.type',
        'serial_number',

      ],
    ]);
```

My SearchModel `ComputerSearch` looks as following:

```
class ComputerSearch extends Computer {
  public $mainboardType;

  public function rules() {
      return [
        // ...
          [['mainboardType'], 'safe'],
      ];
  }

  public function search($params) {
      $query = Computer::find();
      $query->innerJoinWith('mainboard'); // Join for andFilterWhere();

      $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
          'query' => $query,
      ]);

      $this->load($params);

      if (!$this->validate()) {
          return $dataProvider;
      }

      $query->andFilterWhere([Mainboard::tableName() . '.type' => $this->mainboardType]);

      return $dataProvider;
  }
}
```

My Problem: With this code it shows "(not set)" for `mainboard.type`, even though I get all data when I paste the built query and into sql and execute it manually.
When I take out the `innerJoinWith()` line in `ComputerSearch`, the filter would not work anymore, because it cannot find the column `type` in `dbo.Computer` of course, but then the GridView is complete and the mainboard.type field is shown correctly.

Anybody knows how I could filter for `dbo.Mainboard.type` and display it in the view of `Computer`?

Comment: Question is a bit unclear. What i found is your `searchModel` does not have `this->type`. it would be `this->mainboardType` in `andFilerWhere()`. But where is your filter in gridview?

Comment: @InsaneSkull at the end I want to display the mainboard type in the list of computers and at the same time i want the user to be able to filter for the mainboard type. To make it filte-able I have to do innerJoinWith('mainboard') in the SearchModel. But when I do that, it shows "(not set) in the mainboard type column in the computer list view.

Comment: @InsaneSkull but thank you so far, I just fixed the wrong part you mentioned in the example code. My problem is another one though

Comment: It should display `mainboard.type` instead of `not set`. Check the result of `$dataProvider->models` to find relation `mainboard` is populated and contains related data. I guess your related data is empty.

Comment: @InsaneSkull you're right! As long I do the innerJoinWith('mainboard'), $dataProvider->models[0]->mainboard is null, when I remove the innerJoinWith('mainboard') there is the correct mainboard model. Can you tell me why this Issue happens or how I can fix this?

Comment: Your db does not have related data in `mainboard` table. Everything else looks correct to me

Comment: @InsaneSkull Yes for mee also everything looks correct. My db does have related data in mainboard table, but the related model is null when I do the innerJoinWith() before. If I don't do that innerJoinWith() I get the data AND the related models correctly. Its not a data issue! Also I all the data when I print the query with the innerJoinWith() and then execute it in sql manually, so yii2 does something, but I can't understand why..

Comment: You can test answer provided. Nothing else is missing. For further help add both db table data.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing your GridView field `'mainboard.type'` to

```
echo GridView::widget([
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
  'filterModel' => null,
  'columns' => [
    'id',
    'name',
    [
        'attribute' => 'mainboardType',
        'value' => 'mainboard.type',
    ],
    'serial_number',

  ],
]);
```

The rest of your code seems to be fine.
Secondly if your database is case sensitive, I would suggest to manually bring the fields to the same case like that

```
->andFilterWhere(['like', 'LOWER(mainboard.type)', mb_strtolower($this->mainboardType)])
```

And finally if the above does not help, try changing `innerJoinWith` for testing

```
->joinWith('mainboard')
```